# Migrate Non-Salesforce Chat bot into Salesforce Einstein Chat Bot for Service Cloud? Can Einstein bot suggest a link to download firmware update?

Tags: einstein-chatbot, ai

Is this possible to migrate Non-Salesforce Chat bot into Salesforce Einstein Chat Bot for Service Cloud?

If this is true, which settings can be migrated and how?

Also, can Einstein bot suggest a link to download firmware update?

How to implement that?